# Change view that was created programatically

Tags: android

I use a for statement to create and add linearlayouts to a pre-existing vertical linearlayout. When creating them I use the for statement variable to assign an id to each one so the first layout has an id of 0 and the last has an id of 4.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      create layout
      layout.setID(i);
 }
```

I know how to change a view that's created like

```
 Linearlayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout();
 linearLayout.makeSomeChanges;
```

But how do I reference the layouts created in my for statement to make changes to them?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but if you only have 4 sub containers/linearlayouts i'd suggest you just manually place them in the XML. That tends to be easier to work with. If you're doing it programmatically to avoid repeated attributes you can use styles to remove that duplication.

Comment: I want to create them programmatically because the number of layouts and the content of them is dependent on user input. Otherwise I would create the layouts before hand in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with findViewById() function. Suppose we have vertical linear layout called *container*. Now we can inflate there 4 items (in my case this items are linear layout with TextView inside). See the code below:

```
LinearLayout container = findViewById(R.id.container);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    child.setId(i);
    container.addView(child);
}
```

After adding child layouts we can access their views by ids and change any view inside them like I did with TextView:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    View view = container.findViewById(i); // here we get child linear layout
    // now we can access any view inside child linear layout and change it, 
    // or change some parameters of the child layout itself.
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(String.format("Changed Text %d", i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Id should be ideally in resource file to avoid any coflict with existing IDs. In your case if the views are dynamic, it's not a good idea either to put those IDs in resource files.

I would recommend to use setTag() method instead of setId(). Later you can do getViewWithTag() to get the view associated with that tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating View (or layout) objects yourself and adding them to the screen you will have to keep track of them yourself, perhaps by a ArrayList or HashMap or any other way. note that: using setID() you may run into conflicts (two Views with same id), to avoid this you can use View.generateViewId() and keep track of all IDs you get and map them to the View.